# Javascript: Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token Illegal

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and had this snippet working correctly at one time. It is for a background image slider. I cannot figure out what is causing this error. The code is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

window.onload=startslideshow();

var words = [displayimagetwo, displayimagethree, displayimagefour, displayimageone];

var x = 0;

var looptimer;

// (2) define the delayed loop function
function delayedLoop(){
looptimer = setTimeout(function(){
words[x]();
x++;
if (x >= 4) {
x=0;
}
if (x < 4) {
delayedLoop();
}
}, 5000)
}

function displayimageone(){
imgO = document.getElementById("image-one").getElementsByTagName('img');
var str = '';
for(i=0; i < imgO.length; i++){
str += imgO[i].src+"\n";
imageone=str;
// alert(imageone);
document.getElementById("main-image").style.background = "url(" + imageone + ") no-     repeat";
document.getElementById("main-image").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
}

function displayimagetwo(){
imgO = document.getElementById("image-two").getElementsByTagName('img');
var str = '';
for(i=0; i < imgO.length; i++){
str += imgO[i].src+"\n";
imagetwo=str;
// alert(imagetwo);
document.getElementById("main-image").style.background = "url(" + imagetwo + ") no-    repeat";
document.getElementById("main-image").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
}

function displayimagethree(){
imgO = document.getElementById("image-three").getElementsByTagName('img');
var str = '';
for(i=0; i < imgO.length; i++){
str += imgO[i].src+"\n";
imagethree=str;
// alert(imagethree);
document.getElementById("main-image").style.background = "url(" + imagethree + ") no- repeat";
document.getElementById("main-image").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
}

function displayimagefour(){
imgO = document.getElementById("image-four").getElementsByTagName('img');
var str = '';
for(i=0; i < imgO.length; i++){
str += imgO[i].src+"\n";
imagefour=str;
// alert(imagefour);
document.getElementById("main-image").style.background = "url(" + imagefour + ") no-     repeat";
document.getElementById("main-image").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
}
}

function clickimageone(){
clearTimeout(looptimer);
displayimageone();
}

function clickimagetwo(){
clearTimeout(looptimer);
displayimagetwo();
}

function clickimagethree(){
clearTimeout(looptimer);
displayimagethree();
}

function clickimagefour(){
clearTimeout(looptimer);
displayimagefour();
}

function startslideshow(){
delayedLoop();
displayimageone();
}
</script>
```

There error that I am receiving says that the proper is on this line of code:

```
for(i=0; i < imgO.length; i++){
```

The page that I am working on is http://info.morganrandall.com/dp-test. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, as I do not know javascript well enough to really troubleshoot this on my own

Comment: You probably want `window.onload=startslideshow;` (without the parentheses)

Comment: On which of those lines do you get this error? You've a got a lot of duplicated code there.

Comment: For God's sake don't use a 7 MB image for a thumbnail!

Answer (score 1):

The fail is here:

```
str += imgO[i].src+"

";
```

End of line is automatically as a semicolon ';' in this case. If you need more empty lines try something like "\n\n\n".

Comment: are you saying that "\n\n\n" should replace the ';' so the code would look like this?    str += imgO[i].src+"\n\n\n"

Comment: The code should looks this way. The semicolons ';'  are described here: http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript